# AuthenticationVoters has not valid attribute. SpringSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I work on Spring Boot 2.1.

I want all my default endpoints allowed

- either if they're rightly authenticated
- either if they pass on [specific authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521644/spring-boot-specific-url-accessdecisionvoter) rules I've implemented and named * hashSerialSecurityVoter*.

My Code :

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.csrf()
    .disable().cors().and().exceptionHandling()
    /* [...] */
  .anyRequest()
    .authenticated();
    .accessDecisionManager(playerResourceDecisionManager());
}
```

```
@Bean
public AccessDecisionManager playerResourceDecisionManager() {
    List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = Arrays.asList(
        new AuthenticatedVoter(),
        hashSerialSecurityVoter
    );
    return new UnanimousBased(decisionVoters);
}
```

It goes effectivly through both Voters.
But in AuthenticatedVoter, it does not run as I expected.

Even if I'm authenticated, it returns *ACCESS_ABSTAIN*  value.

When I debug it, I've noticed that Manager does not provide any ConfigAttribute.
So `authenticatedVoter.supports()` methods returns false..

Do I miss something on accessDecisionManager declaration ?

Results is that my main API client does not work anymore because all my requests are returned with 403.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `WebExpressionVoter` into your AccessDecisionManger.

`.authenticated()`, `.fullyAuthenticated()`, `.anonymous()` all create
WebExpressionConfigAttribute objects.

`AuthenticatedVoter` (IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY attribute) is used in Spring XML security configurations.

Spring Security: v5.7.8